# PHP Upgrade to 8 with Error Options -Indexes in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php-8

Have upgraded PHP 7.4 to to PHP 8.2.1 on mac osx, and for some reason, can not locate what is causing an issue with the .htaccess file having this code in it:

```
Options -Indexes -Multiviews
```

If I remove this code the site loads, but than shows all folders and files which is not desirable.  Need site to load the index.php file that is being shown here, trying to hide this, but once this is in the .htaccess file, I'm getting the following error message:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Is there something in PHP that needs to be set?  I did change the php_module to point to PHP 8 in the httpd.conf file, so I don't understand what else might need to change to get my localhost loaded properly instead of showing files and folders?

BTW, this was working fine on PHP 7.4, but after updating, no longer works.  Maybe I have to install other modules for 8.2.1 to work correctly?

If I switch back to using PHP 7.4 everything is loading fine on the site after restarting apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Need site to load the index.php file

You need to set the `DirectoryIndex` (mod_dir) - this defaults to `index.html` only (an Apache issue, not PHP). It is the `DirectoryIndex` that determines which file(s) Apache will try to serve when requesting a directory.

For example:

```
Options -Indexes -Multiviews

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If a `DirectoryIndex` document (there can be more than 1) is not found... and mod_autoindex is disabled (ie. `-Indexes`) then you get a 403 Forbidden response. If mod_autoindex is enabled then you naturally see a directory listing. (If mod_autoindex is not installed at all then you get a 404 Not Found.)

mod_autoindex (ie. `Indexes`) is not enabled by default on Apache 2.4 (it is on Apache 2.2), however, it has likely been explicitly enabled elsewhere in the server config.

Comment: The problem was actually the type for php has changed from what php 7 was using to what php 8 is using.  I fixed this in the .conf file and it works perfectly now.  the `AddType` part of the conf was wrong, but all good now.  DirectoryIndex had index.html index.php in apache's httpd.conf file so that wasn't the problem, it was the php `AddType` part is different now in PHP 8.2.1.  Thanks for your help though.