# .htaccess works for .html but not .php

Tags: .htaccess, windows-server-2019

I want to restrict the access to my directory (and redirect to my index.php)
but it is not working well. When i change the extension from PHP to HTML it works fine, but I cannot make it work for php

This is what I have in my .htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

I'm new to all of this, so I really don't know how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache server. You can check this by running `apachectl -M`, and look for `rewrite_module (shared)`.
If mod_rewrite is not enabled then you can enable it by adding `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in your httpd.conf file.

Comment: Also, check your PHP handler is set correctly in Apache. Make sure that PHP is being handled by the correct handler, such as mod_php or PHP-FPM.

Comment: sorry if my question sounds dumb... but where can I check those things?

Comment: On Windows, the Apache configuration files, including httpd.conf, are typically located in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\conf` or `C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\conf` directory.

Comment: i found in `httpd.conf` this line: `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. I removed the # and retried, but it doesn't did anything

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict access to my directory"? The directives you posted don't "restrict access". What request/URL are you making to test this? What are you expecting to happen? If you are literally requesting the root directory, eg. `https://example.com/` then the relevant directives in your question would not apply anyway and this would look like a `DirectoryIndex` issue? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75076740/369434